# Getting a path through a dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, stack

I have a dictionary that maps strings to sets of strings. As a toy example:

```
d = {'a': {'b', 'c', 'd'},
 'b': {'c', 'x'},
 'c': {'d', 'z'}}
```

The idea is that each string maps to a set of strings, each of which maps again to its own set of strings, etc.

I want a function `f(start, d, pathLength)` that will take a starting string, the dictionary, and a path length, and return the first path through the dictionary that it can find, of length pathLength. One invariant is that a path cannot continue if its last element is equal to a value already present in the path.

I wrote code that constructs the whole tree recursively, but this is quite computationally intensive, and seems unnecessary. To reduce the time required, I had it build take nodes with a certain probability. I would like to retain the stochastic feature, such that each time the function is run, we get a different path in return. I figure there's a way to do this using a stack and loop without recursion, but I haven't succeeded.

Comment: Guido van Rossum has a good essay on this here: https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic algorithm in graph theory; please search for how to find a path through a directed graph.  [Dijktra's algorithm](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/119466-dijkstras-algorithm-for-shortest-paths/) is the standard for shortest path.  However, if you want *exactly* the given path length, you'll need to alter it a little.

In general, you will want to keep a list of how many steps it takes you to get to each node: keep all possibilities, instead of just the shortest.  The general outline is:

```
**search list** <- start node
**found list** <- []
While the **search list** is not empty:
   Pop the next node (call it **here**) from the search list.
   If the current path length < desired path length:
      For each node **next** reachable from **here**:
         If **next** is already on the **found list**, 
            Add the present path to its entry on the found list.
            Follow the downstream paths from **here** and update their paths with the new path to **here** (alternate solutions).
         Else
            Add **next** and the present path to the **found list**.
            Add **next** to the search list.
```